# Converting pipe-delimited file to spark dataframe to CSV file

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I have a CSV file with one single column and the rows are defined as follows :

```
123 || food || fruit
123 || food || fruit || orange 
123 || food || fruit || apple
```

I want to create a csv file with a single column and distinct row values as :

```
orange
apple
```

I tried using the following code :

```
 val data = sc.textFile("fruits.csv")
 val rows = data.map(_.split("||"))
 val rddnew = rows.flatMap( arr => {
 val text = arr(0) 
 val words = text.split("||")
 words.map( word => ( word, text ) )
 } )
```

But this code is not giving me the correct result as wanted. 
Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 5):

you need to split with escape for special characters, since split takes regex

```
.split("\\|\\|")
```

converting to CSV is tricky because data strings may potentially contain your delimiter (in quotes), new-line or other parse-sensitive characters, so I'd recommend using [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

```
 val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter", "||")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("words.csv")
```

and

```
 words.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter", "||")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("words.csv")
```

Comment: How to add |^|  delimiter in spark csv output ?

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this problem similar to this code

```
val text = sc.textFile("fruit.csv")
val word = text.map( l => l.split("\\|\\|")
val last = word.map( w => w(w.size - 1))
last.distinct.collect
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked but i also wanted to save the results as a csv file. I tried doing last.distinct.collect.saveAsTextFile() but it does not work stating that saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[String]. Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: @user2122466 `saveAsTextFile` is defined on an RDD. What is the type of `last.distinct.collect` ?

Comment: @maasg : It is an Array[string]. thank you for that.

Comment: @user2122466 exactly :-)

Comment: How to add |^| delimiter in spark csv output ?