# How to read .DAT file using SCALA

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read DAT file using below syntax but getting below error:

```
spark.read.format("dat").option("header", "true").option("delimiter","!^")
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: dat. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: i need to load multiple file so i am using variable in load .schema(RC32_schema).load(s"FILEPATH/"+var)

Comment: Can you tell us if is binary data or text?

Comment: if i a using this i m able to read spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter","^") but restricted for delimiter only character but file is delimited by two character

Comment: it is simple text data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .csv(spark.read.textFile("filename")
  .map(line => line.split("YOUR DOUBLE DELIMITER").mkString("\t")))
```

The answer is from here:
[How to use double pipe as delimiter in CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268182/how-to-use-double-pipe-as-delimiter-in-csv)

Comment: Not getting expected result every line come in one column